# Android Actionbar compatibility alternate xml for pre-honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-actionbar-compat

I am using the actiobarcompat sample in my application and I am trying to implement search for pre 3.0 devices.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

On Honeycomb+ this works fine, the searchview widget appears in the actionbar. What I am trying to do is have a second menu XML so I can fall back to the old search activity way of doing it. However, there is no such thing as menu-v11 folder as the menu folder is essentially menu-v11 because that is the version it started supporting this.

My question is, using the actionbar compatibility sample, is there a way to declaratively  add an alternate button for pre-honeycomb?

Comment: Have you considered using ActionBar Sherlock?

Comment: I have.. they ARE both Apache... its complicated though. I am walking the line of if the suits are going to allow me to use either of these components in the first place. it may be all for naught.

Comment: @TomFobear: Well ABS (ActionBarSherlock) is under a Apache License if that is what you meant. And if it all hinges on the _suits_ accepting the use of such a lib, you should put all the options on the table. If they need the feature, they will need to choose, I suspect, most probably ABS.

Comment: What's the problem with using Apache Licensed libraries? Many commercial apps use ActionBar Sherlock, Foursquare does, for example. It's not GPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

It it's about calling different activities depending on API version, the action bar has nothing to do with that.
You analyse API version in onOptionsItemSelected and act accordingly.

If you want different menu items depending on API version, just create a folder *menu-v11* (or *menu-v14*) and put
version-specific xml-s- there.

BTW, I use *com.android.actionbarcompat* and it works great for me!

Comment: I've actually figured out a solution to my specific problem but would prefer to not answer my own question. The problem is in ActionBarHelperBase in method loadActionBarMetadata it will only add the menu item if it is shown always or ifRoom.. but not the OR'd combination of collapseActionItem and ifRoom.